# Returning a promise gives "Supplied parameters do not match" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, promise

I am in the middle of converting a jQuery plugin to use `promises` instead of `callbacks`. This should be very basic, but not sure if the problem is my approach in chaining promises, my return type, or TypeScript just being fussy.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error   27  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Type '(value: {}) => {}' requires a call signature, but type 'JQueryPromise<any>' lacks one.
```

A cut-down version of my function looks like this:

```
    _navigate(forward: boolean, $panel: JQuery, target: string): JQueryPromise<any>
    {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        switch (target)
        {
            // '_self' is a full page load link
            case '_self':
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    window.location.href = url;
                }, 0);

                // Return empty promise - as we are about to lose the page
                dfd.resolve(true);
                break;
            // _back re-displays a panel already loaded
            case '_back':
                // Fetch a reference to the panel before this one
                var $existingPanel = THIS._getNextPanel($panel, false);

    // >>>> ERROR ON NEXT LINE <<<<<<
                // This will animate back in the previous panel - promise on complete
                dfd = dfd.then(THIS._gotoPanel($existingPanel, false, true, target));

                break;
    // [SNIP]
        }
        return dfd.promise();
    }
```

_gotoPanel is just another method that also returns a `JQueryPromise<any>` promise:

```
    _gotoPanel($panel: JQuery, forward: boolean, transition: boolean, target?: string): JQueryPromise<any>
```

The final version needs to be able to chain any number of promises from methods and `$.ajax` calls but I keep hitting this error. What should my return type look like if not `JQueryPromise<any>`?

Answer (score 1):

> What should my return type look like if not `JQueryPromise<any>`?

As the error message `'(value: {}) => {}' requires a call signature` says, you need to pass a **callback** to [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), instead of a promise!

I think you want just

```
dfd = THIS._gotoPanel($existingPanel, false, true, target);
```

as the `dfd` would otherwise not be resolved at all in the `_back` case.

Comment: That makes sense. Assuming I have multiple promises to combine (so `dfd = THIS._gotoPanel($existingPanel, false, true, target);` would not work, what is your suggested method of chaining the promises?

Comment: How do you want to combine them? Does chaining mean that they are executed sequentially, because they depend on the previous results? Please show your whole code.

Comment: Interesting. I am curious to see how this works when chaining multiple calls e.g. `doThat().then( () => { dfd = doThis() } )` because you are  somehow reassigning the closure variable `dfd` in the future.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't work. The point of `then` is that it returns a promise for the result of the promise generated in the future by the callback: `dfd = doThat().then(() => { return doThis() })`

Comment: @Bergi I do not like the idea of reassigning `dfd` and feel it should be considered `final`. Yet, reassigning it to the *first* future call should be OK. Anyway, if you chain, why assign `$.Deferred()` to dfd in the first place? `var dfd = doThat().then(() => { return doThis() })` is good enough. If you want to resolve immediately: `var dfd = $.when(resolveThis)` is fine (and a common pattern as far as I can tell).

Comment: Sure, and you [shouldn't use much deferreds anyway](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). I did it just because it fits into your code, it technically even isn't a deferred but a promise. Actually I'd simply `return` from the function and not use a "result" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I guess you need to provide the type information to `then` e.g. `then<any>`

If you don't, jQuery wraps another `JQueryPromise` around the return type of the function within the `then`

Anyway, I personally would not wrap the method inside a `$.Deferred()`, but would rather, return `$.when(true)` instead of `dfd.resolve(true)` and would directly return `THIS._gotoPanel(...)`

**EDIT**

`var d = $.Deferred(); d = d.then(blah); return d.promise()` does not fly

If wrapping in a `Deferred`, something along the lines of:

```
_navigate(forward: boolean, $panel: JQuery, target: string): JQueryPromise<any>
{
    return $.Deferred(dfd => {
        switch (target) {
            // '_self' is a full page load link
            case '_self':
                ....
                dfd.resolve(true);
                break;

            case '_back':
                THIS._gotoPanel($existingPanel, false, true, target)).then(
                    ()  => { dfd.resolve(whatever); },
                    err => { dfd.reject(err); }
                )
                break;
          }
     }).promise();
}
```

Comment: This was a cut-down example. I often needed to run multiple promises, sometime in parallel, sometime sequentially, so returning the other call won't help.

Comment: Just checked. `dfd.then<any>(...)` does not compile, but thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: OK. Still the construction `var d = $.Deferred(); d = d.then(blah); return d.promise()` does not fly (try it on a snippet). I believe that you must either warp everything in a `Deferred` and always  `resolve` / `reject` or chain promises

Comment: So basically you recommend chaining by catching the `done` and `reject` of each child promise and passing back results via `resolve` and `reject`. That will work, just not as simple as I had hoped.

Comment: Yes or use the `$.when` "trick" and not wrap in a `Deferred`. I agree on the boilerplate. Writing a lot of these currently, I find I am writing way too much code. I also find that I need to specify the type on nearly every `then` to avoid high compilation times and compilation errors. Some people report `Q` is a better promises framework; I have not tested it

Comment: The conversion is going better and I will update question (or add a new one) once I have things in place. This may be a stupid question, but what does the type in `JQueryPromise<T>` actually specify? It would make sense to be able to define the resolve parameters that get passed to `done`, but I can't see how you could define that.

Comment: The type is the one of the variable encapsulated in the `resolve`/success response. There is no way to specify the failure types as far as I know (and is a big weakness IMHO). Assuming `d`is a `JQueryPromise<T>`,    `d.done(a => { //a is of type T })` , `d.fail(e => { //e is of an unspecified type })`

Comment: (correction) `d` is a  `JQueryPromise<T>`  ->  `d` returns a  `JQueryPromise<T>`